# Nested routing with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a (likely stupid) AngularJS question involving nested UI Router configurations, hoping the fine community here can help.

Basically, I have a standard app.routes.js for the main menu links. Code (trimmed to whats valuable and generified):

```
angular.module('app',[
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'app.links'
])
    .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('index',{
                url:'/',
                views:{
                    'index':{
                        templateUrl:'app/app.view.html'
                    },
                    'header@index':{
                        templateUrl:'app/components/core/header/header.view.html',
                        controller:'HeaderController as headerCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve:{
                    loadLayoutModules:['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            {
                                name:'app.header',
                                serie:true,
                                files: [
                                    'app/components/core/header/header.module.js',
                                    'app/components/core/header/header.service.js',
                                    'app/components/core/header/header.controller.js',
                                    'app/components/links/links.module.js',
                                    'app/components/links/links.routes.js'
                                ]
                            }
                        ]);
                    }]
                }
            })
```

I have several other `.state()`s in the chain for each link, standard menu stuff. However, one of the links has a submenu, and I specifically wanted to segregate out the configuration of those to a separate file ... `app/componenets/links/links.routes.js`. It's code:

```
angular.module('app.links',[])
    .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('index.links.first',{
                url:'links/first',
                views:{
                    'main@index':{
                        templateUrl:'app/components/links/first/first.view.html',
                        controller:'FirstLinkController as firstLinkCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve:{
                    loadFirstLinkModules:['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            {
                                name:'app.home',
                                serie:true,
                                files: [
                                    'app/components/links/first/first.module.js',
                                    'app/components/links/first/first.service.js',
                                    'app/components/links/first/first.controller.js'
                                ]
                            }
                        ]);
                    }]
                }
            });
    }]);
```

Nothing too crazy here. The problem is that this `.config()` is not firing at all. I put a `console.log()` at the top of it just to test; even though the file itself is being loaded, the `.config()` function for the module never runs.

Based on the [UI Router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-ui-router-from-multiple-modules), I should be able to use multiple modules to establish routing. Is it because I'm lazy loading the file? Is there something that I am missing? Please help!!

By the way, if anyone is wondering why I want to separate these states out, it is because it is for scaling ... just assume this will be used for a site with like 10,000 states, and this is to organize the routing to those states better. With that context in mind, if you recommend a different methodology, I'm all ears! I'm pretty new to Angular, and welcome any and all wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, nothing wrong with separating out routes into multiple files. I do that successfully in all my angular apps. See my angular starter app here: https://github.com/RyanWarner/angular-sprout.

I can't comment yet, but are you remembering to require your `links` module as a dependency to your app module?

Example from the UI router docs:

```
angular.module('main', ['main.page1']);
```

Where `main.page1` is equivalent to the module you call `links`.

Comment: Let me give this a try ... I did not do this because of the lazy loading I was doing. I didn't want to have a `<script>` tag for every file, but for the nested routing it may be unavoidable.

Comment: In development, I use [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject) with [gulp-angular-filesort](https://github.com/klei/gulp-angular-filesort) to take care of all the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Alright so I double-checked, by avoiding lazy loading the config function fires now, it just doesnt go to the state. Another puzzle to solve, I'll checkmark this because the issue was solved.

Comment: Do you have an `index.links` state? Parents MUST exist.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#parent-must-exist

Comment: yup, i figured out very quickly that I needed an `index.links` state ... i just set the `url` to be `links/` and `abstract` to be `true` ... works as expected now. thanks for your help!